# So large (plural)

Tags: adverbs

*So large a head* and *so large a number*, both singular, are possible, but is *so large people* also possible, or does this construction not work for plurals, (meaning only *such large people* is correct)?

Comment: That construction doesn't work for plurals, because they don't use indefinite articles. _Such_ is normally used for nouns: _Such a large head, such large heads, such colorful flooring/azaleas,_ etc. _So_ is for adjectives, normally only as predicates: _So beautiful, so hot, so pregnant,_ but the special construction allows the _so large_ part to appear before an indefinite noun phrase _a head_; it's an idiom. _So large a head_ means the same thing as _such a large head_. And both of them can refer to a complement clause -- _so large a head/such a large head that he can't find a hat to fit._

Comment: "So large a people" is possible.  The primary meaning is an ethnic group or nation with a large population.
"So large a person" is also possible.  Besides size, it also is frequently used to express a person, usually in politics, who has accomplished much and is well known, in a positive sense.

Comment: Related: [If I can say “not that good a review,” does that mean I can say “not that good reviews”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343861) As John Lawler said, most people only find these kinds of constructions acceptable if there is an indefinite article "a" or "an", and since this can only occur before singular nouns, it is not possible to use a plural noun.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> That construction doesn't work for plurals, because they don't use indefinite articles. *Such* is normally used for nouns: *Such a large head, such large heads, such colorful flooring/azaleas,* etc. *So* is for adjectives, normally only as predicates: *So beautiful, so hot, so pregnant,* but the special construction allows the *so large* part to appear before an indefinite noun phrase *a head*; it's an idiom. *So large a head* means the same thing as *such a large head*. And both of them can refer to a complement clause -- *so large a head/such a large head that he can't find a hat to fit.*